# Mocking returns null when using with @SpringBootTest and @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)

Tags: java, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have snippet code as follows that when trying to mock object it returns null:

`userInfoDto` is null.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class IntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    private UserInfoDto userInfo;
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        when(userInfo.getXCaller()).thenReturn("Test");
    }

}
```

Comment: When using `MockitoExtension`, you don't have to call `openMocks` (and openMocks should be called for the test class, not the field).

Comment: @knittl I updated the question and still same error

Comment: Is `userInfo` and `userInfoDto` a typo or your real code? One doesn't exist, the other is never used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

For

```
@InjectMocks
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

I'm assuming your `UserInfoDto` is `@Autowired` in original class and the `UserRepository` is the class you're trying to test